# resilience4j circuit breaker change fallback method return type than actual called method return type

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am trying to learn Spring Boot microservices. Now I am trying to implement circuit breaker with resilience4j if any of my called service is off.

If I set the fallback method return type as like the actual method return type than it works fine but I can't show the information that my service is off. Because it then send the response null in object's fields. But if I change the return type to String on actual method and also in fallback then I will not be able to get the object value as JSON.

Is it possible to return as string something like `Branch service is down!..` with my fallback method and if OK then get the object value as JSON from actual called method? My attempts are below:

My controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "default", fallbackMethod = "employeeFallback")
public ResponseModelEmployee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return employeeService.findByEmployeeId(id);
}
```

My fallback method in controller:

```
public ResponseModelEmployee employeeFallback(Long id, Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseModelEmployee();
    }
```

My service method called from controller:

```
public ResponseModelEmployee findByEmployeeId(Long id) {
        ResponseModelEmployee empDetails = new ResponseModelEmployee();
        ...
        Branch branch = restTemplate.getForObject("http://BRANCH-SERVICE/branch/getById/" +
                employee.get().getBranchId(),
                Branch.class);

        ...

        return empDetails;
    }
```

My desire method as fallback:

```
public String employeeFallback(Long id, Exception ex) {
        return "Branch Service is down";
    }
```

If I set my desire method for fallback then it gives the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class com.example.employee.VO.ResponseModelEmployee class com.example.employee.controller.EmployeeController.employeeFallback(class java.lang.Long,class java.lang.Throwable) at io.github.resilience4j.fallback.FallbackMethod.create(FallbackMethod.java:92) ~[resilience4j-spring-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0] ....`

Comment: from my interpretation of your question, it sounds like you don't actually need a fallback value to use when the network call fails. Is this correct?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen of course I need the fallback reason

Comment: the purpose of a fallback value isn't to explain why the network call failed. That is the purpose of an exception. The fallback value is a default that you can use in the case that the network call fails.

Answer (score 3):

Resilince4j expects the fallback method to have the same return type as of the actual method.
[Documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/v1.0.0/docs/getting-started-3) says:

> It's important to remember that a fallback method should be placed in
> the same class and must have the same method signature with just ONE
> extra target exception parameter).
>
> If there are multiple fallbackMethod methods, the method that has the
> most closest match will be invoked, for example:
> If you try to recover from NumberFormatException, the method with
> signature String fallback(String parameter, IllegalArgumentException
> exception)} will be invoked.
>
> You can define one global fallback method with an exception parameter
> only if multiple methods has the same return type and you want to
> define the same fallback method for them once and for all.

So, you cannot directly change the return type to a different one.
You can try few suggestions:

- Add `@CircuitBreaker` and `fallback` to the service method.
- Change return type of service method and fallback method to `Object`.
- One more way could be , you can keep the return type as it is but add a `String` type message object to response model `ResponseModelEmployee`. Then set message string to it during fallback.
- Another solution could be to return ResponseEntity from the from the method where rest call is made and in the fallback method use ResponseEntity<?> as response object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object as a return type

in my case for example:

```
@GetMapping("/getUser/{id}")
@CircuitBreaker(name= something , fallbackMethod = "ContactsServiceDown")
public ResponseEntity<User> getDetailsById(@PathVariable(id)){
     //some logic
 return new ResponseEntity<User>(user , HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<Object> ContactsServiceDown(int id , Exception e){
    //some logic
  return new ResponseEntity<Object>("ContactsServersDown", HttpStatus.Forbidden)
}
```

or in returnType ResponseEntity<> leave the type Field empty, hopefully it may work!